# Migrate from FUSE ESB to JBOSS FUSE

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse

We are considering to upgrade an existing system which used FUSE ESB 4.4.1 to latest JBOSS FUSE.
From what I understand, JBOSS FUSE is the much newer version of FUSE ESB. But I have no idea how much have it changed and does the code we have already implemented in FUSE ESB possible to run on latest JBOSS FUSE without extensive changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to migrate. Only if you use JBI components then they are deprecated and no longer supported in the upcoming JBoss Fuse 6.2 release. But for OSGi applications you may have developed for the old Fuse ESB, then it should be possible to recompile and deploy as-is, or there is some minor migration effort. Its primary the upgrades to Camel / CXF that may drive migration changes upon you. Or if you are unlucky then OSGi itself may cause a bit of pain to upgrade, as its errors sometimes can be hard to understand and figure out how to resolve.

There is some migration guides at JBoss Fuse documentation, you can find here

- http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/resources/

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful.